# NewConnectionError: Trying to consume and then serve predictions from the served model in FastAPI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I have deployed my TensorFlow prediction model in a container using TensorFlow/serving and I have a FastAPI in another container trying to consume and then serve predictions from the served model.

I am able to serve the model successfully at *http://localhost:8501/v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict*. And I am able to use the model for prediction from my local. But I get the following error when trying to access the served model using FastAPI.

I am getting the **error**:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=9, connect=2, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f94f6768280>: Fa
iled to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict
```

**FastAPI**

```
@app.post('/predict/')
def predict_car_efficiency(data):
    if data is None:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Please provide an image when calling this request")
    instances = {"instances": data}
    data_json = json.dumps(instances)
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)

    json_response = session.post("http://localhost:8501/v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict", 
    data=data_json, headers=headers)
    return json_response.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.3'


services:
  tensorflow-serving:
    container_name: model-deploy
    image: tensorflow/serving
    ports:
      - '8500:8500'
      - '8501:8501'
    networks:
      - custom-network
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./deploy_model/models/dnn_model
        target: /models/dnn_model
      - type: bind
        source: ./deploy_model/models/models.config
        target: /models/models.config
    command:
      - '--model_config_file=/models/models.config'
  api:
    container_name: api_service
    build:
      context: ./Serve_API
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    networks:
      - custom-network
    command: uvicorn src.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

networks:
    custom-network:
```

First time trying a project like this, What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I am able to access a my model from FastAPI by explicitly naming the container name in the URL *http://model-deploy:8501/v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict*.

Is it the correct approach?
what is the alternative?

Comment: So which application is `http://localhost:8501/v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict` referring to? You're not starting anything inside your docker container that seems to run on that port or hasn't mentioned any apps that contain that functionality.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am trying to replicate this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsM81oUn3v4) to serve my model

Comment: Sorry, but watching a 19 minute video to understand what you're trying to do is a bit too much. Add relevant details to your question, but generally - the connection error happens because there is no application running on `localhost:8501` - whether you expect there to be an application there or what that application is is relevant to how you'd solve the issue (i.e. is it a docker issue with accessing the host's network, do you expect more than one application to run in a container, do you want two containers to talk to each other, etc.)

Comment: I might start with [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation, if you want the two containers to talk to each other.  I'd also suggest simplifying the setup by removing several unnecessary options; you should be able to remove all of the `networks:` and `container_name:` settings, the default-value `build: { dockerfile: }`, and the application's `command:` override.